# Extracting Data from Multiple TXT Files and Creating a Summary CSV File in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, export-to-csv

I have a folder with about 50 .txt files containing data in the following format.

```
=== Predictions on test data ===

 inst#     actual  predicted error distribution (OFTd1_OF_Latency)
     1        1:S        2:R   +   0.125,*0.875 (73.84)
```

I need to write a program that combines the following: my index number (i), the letter of the true class (R or S), the letter of the predicted class, and each of the distribution predictions (the decimals less than 1.0).

I would like it to look like the following when finished, but preferably as a .csv file.

```
ID   True   Pred   S      R
1    S      R      0.125  0.875
2    R      R      0.105  0.895
3    S      S      0.945  0.055
.    .      .      .      .
.    .      .      .      .
.    .      .      .      .
n    S      S      0.900  0.100
```

I'm a beginner and a bit fuzzy on how to get all of that parsed and then concatenated and appended. Here's what I was thinking, but feel free to suggest another direction if that would be easier.

```
for i in range(1, n):
   s = str(i)
   readin = open('mydata/output/output'+s+'out','r')
   #The files are all named the same but with different numbers associated
   output = open("mydata/summary.csv", "a")
   storage = []
   for line in readin:
     #data extraction/concatenation here
     if line.startswith('1'):
        id = i
        true = # split at the ':' and take the letter after it
        pred = # split at the second ':' and take the letter after it
         #some have error '+'s and some don't so I'm not exactly sure what to do to get the distributions
        ds = # split at the ',' and take the string of 5 digits before it
        if pred == 'R':
           dr = #skip the character after the comma but take the have characters after
        else: 
           #take the five characters after the comma
        lineholder = id+' , '+true+' , '+pred+' , '+ds+' , '+dr
     else: continue
   output.write(lineholder)
```

I think using the indexes would be another option, but it might complicate things if the spacing is off in any of the files and I haven't checked this for sure.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all, if you want to use CSV, you should use CSV module that comes with python. More about this module here: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html I won't demonstrate how to use it, because it's pretty simple.

As for reading the input data, here's my suggestion how to break down every line of the data itself. I assume that lines of data in the input file have their values separated by spaces, and each value cannot contain a space:

```
def process_line(id_, line):
    pieces = line.split() # Now we have an array of values
    true = pieces[1].split(':')[1] # split at the ':' and take the letter after it
    pred = pieces[2].split(':')[1] # split at the second ':' and take the letter after it
    if len(pieces) == 6: # There was an error, the + is there
        p4 = pieces[4]
    else: # There was no '+' only spaces
        p4 = pieces[3]
    ds = p4.split(',')[0] # split at the ',' and take the string of 5 digits before it
    if pred == 'R':
        dr = p4.split(',')[0][1:] #skip the character after the comma but take the have??? characters after
    else:
        dr = p4.split(',')[0]
    return id_+' , '+true+' , '+pred+' , '+ds+' , '+dr
```

What I mainly used here was split function of strings: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split and in one place this simple syntax of str[1:] to skip the first character of the string (strings are arrays after all, we can use this slicing syntax).

Keep in mind that my function won't handle any errors or lines formated differently than the one you posted as an example. If the values in every line are separated by tabs and not spaces you should replace this line: `pieces = line.split()` with `pieces = line.split('\t')`.

Comment: Worked really well with a couple of modifications (putting ds under the if/else because if pred = S, then it had the asterisk). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i think u can separte floats and then combine it with the strings with the help of re module as follows:

```
import re
file = open('sample.txt','r')
strings=[[num for num in re.findall(r'\d+\.+\d+',i) for i in file.readlines()]]
print (strings)
file.close()
file = open('sample.txt','r')
num=[[num for num in re.findall(r'\w+\:+\w+',i) for i in file.readlines()]]
print (num)
s= num+strings
print s #[['1:S','2:R'],['0.125','0.875','73.84']] output of the code
```

this prog is written for one line u can use it for multiple line as well but u need to use a loop for that

contents of sample.txt:
 1        1:S        2:R   +   0.125,*0.875 (73.84)

2        1:S        2:R   +   0.15,*0.85 (69.4)

when you run the prog the result will be:
[['1:S,'2:R'],['1:S','2:R'],['0.125','0.875','73.84'],['0.15,'0.85,'69.4']]

simply concatenate them

Answer (score 0):

This uses regular expressions and the CSV module.

```
import re
import csv

matcher = re.compile(r'[[:blank:]]*1.*:(.).*:(.).* ([^ ]*),[^0-9]?(.*) ')
filenametemplate = 'mydata/output/output%iout'

output = csv.writer(open('mydata/summary.csv', 'w'))

for i in range(1, n):
    for line in open(filenametemplate % i):
        m = matcher.match(line)
        if m:
           output.write([i] + list(m.groups()))
```